# How to compose/ transform 2D object views (front, back, L/R sides, top & bottom) into a single 3D image

Tags: modeling, mesh, vector-mapping

[[image: 2D flats below represent the 6 images that i would like to combine to create a 3D rendering]
Can Blender compose/ transform 6 seperate 2D object views (front, back, L/R sides, top & bottom) that have been created in Illustrator (native vector file, 2D) into a 3D image? For example, make a 3D golf bag from 2D flat images

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any automatic way to do it. You can use your image as a blueprint, create the 3 shapes (top, front and side):

[image]

Then extrude them:

[image]

Boolean the front and side (*Intersect* mode):

[image]*

Use top and bottom faces to model the top and bottom of your mesh:

[image]